# Process pv output to write status to a file while running

Tags: bash, io-redirection, pv

I want to monitor the progress of a very large tarball extraction in a shell script.  The monitoring process can watch files, so I am thinking if I could get the output of `pv` to pipe to a script I could have that script write the status to a file

What I'm trying to do is something like this, but it's not working:

```
pv -p bundle.tgz | tar xz -Coutdir 2>&1 | <script to parse output>
```

What I really want is to overwrite a single file like 'status' with the percentage progress coming out of `pv`.

Anyone know enough about bash pipes to make this work?

Comment: Do you want `pv -n` to a regular file named `status` *and* `pv -p` to stdout at the same time?